# ASP.NET Core + Spa (react) | returns too much information. Custom error message

Tags: reactjs, api, asp.net-core-5.0

I setup a ASP.NET Core 5.0 project with Spa extension - Reactjs.

Whenever a call is made using whatever URL, the server returns the main index page. Reactjs routes are the one controlling what content to load. This works fine.

If the URL starts with `/api` then IF there is an error, it returns an error instead of the index page. Works fine.

**The issue:**
When there is an error, it returns way too much information. By default, it returns a JSON object with `config`, that contains a lot of info, `data`, `headers`, `request` and so on. I wish to minimize the information when on production mode with just like few lines, for example just `{ StatusCode: <code> }`. But whatever I try, I get the same result.

So far my Startup.cs `Configure` method looks like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());

        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            return next();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa => spa.Options.SourcePath = "ReactJs");
    }
```

I tired MANY things to implement this. I tried this:

```
        app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
        {
            var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

            await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new { error = exception.Message });
        }));
```

I tried creating my own Error controllers and what not - still returns same data!

I tried pretty much all the things from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

How do I configure how and what the error message gets returned from my bad API request to a method, or even a controller, that does not exist? Should NOT be specific to just 1 method/controller.

The data I get:

[image]

The ONLY data , for example, wish to get:

[image]

**Long story short**: Make it so front-end receives less information from an API when an error happens.

Comment: Does this occur on production builds?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Yes, with an exception of `Stack`. that doe snot appear. When uploading a photo I forgot to change back to production to re-take a photo. So  I corrected the image. But the issue is still the same